# How to allow users to navigate the page while a javascript alert is up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently, I have a javascript alert, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Hopefully you will not see this screen too long, because that would mean that it is taking a while to load my page.');
        </script>
```

I just have filler text right now, but I was wondering how to make it so that the popup will stay open, but the user can still click around and navigate the page. Right now, while open, no clicks can be made on the page.

Comment: Not possible. You are better off implementing your own (or using a library) JavaScript/CSS alternative, such as a bootstrap [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's how the browser works. Nothing else can be done while an alert is active. Overall, it's a better user experience to implement your own. Recommend you use an alert library... my favorite is http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

JQuery and Bootstrap both offer equivalents also.